# How can I get the PHP's tar.gz file via terminal?

Tags: php, linux, bash, tar, gzip

I've been trying to download the PHP's tar.gz file with the following command:

```
  sudo wget php.net/get/php-5.6.4.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
```

But all that I get is a file named "mirro". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use http://php.net/distributions/php-5.6.4.tar.gz

Comment: see this link http://www.howtogeek.com/194160/how-to-download-php-source-from-the-terminal-with-wget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Try this Command..

Hope it will work from you

wget -O php-5.5.14.tar.gz http://us.php.net/get/php-5.5.14.tar.gz/from/this/mirror

Whenever you want to force the output from the Wget command into a specific filename, you just need to use the -O argument (that’s a capital letter o), or the longer version, --output-document=FILE that is a lot of extra typing for no reason.